# How can I improve my questions?

Tags: support, questions

So I've been asking some questions on stack exchange here, and I got question banned. I read the article at the help center on asking good questions. I can't improve my questions (mostly because they are already answered). I deleted some of my questions (which don't help) but no one thinks they're good! Also, very few people are viewing my previous questions which I think *might* be a factor. Some tips on asking good questions would be appreciated. **Also, do not copy and paste the tips from the help center.**

Comment: A good question doesn't depend on how many questions you've asked before. What question(s) are you talking about exactly? In your history are only two questions with negative score (not counting deleted ones). Also deleting a question has a negative impact as well.

Comment: Agreed with dly - can you post some specific examples of questions you'd like feedback on?

Comment: I deleted a bunch of questions, including my first one with a score of -7

Comment: Without example questions we can't help you. Deleted content is not available on Data and the search tools we have are quite limited. If you still have a link to the deleted question that would help a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your two undeleted and negative-score questions, ["Minecraft multiple data tag command help"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/320551/minecraft-multiple-data-tag-command-help) and ["Fortnite mobile update problem"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/345915/fortnite-mobile-update-problem), I can think of some tips. These tips will reference those from the help centre, but they are relevant to these questions:

Show some evidence of research in your questions - evidence that you have attempted to solve the question yourself. A general rule of thumb is that your question should not be able to be solved from clicking one link from a google search. For your Minecraft question, I was able to find [two](https://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/minecraft-java-edition/redstone-discussion-and/commands-command-blocks-and/2244696-data-tag-parsing-failed-invalid-tag-encountered) [links](https://www.reddit.com/r/MinecraftCommands/wiki/errors/) to solve it by [Googling](https://www.google.com/search?q=Data%20tag%20parsing%20failed%3A%20Expected%20non-empty%20key%20at%3A&rlz=1C5CHFA_enAU751AU751&oq=Data%20tag%20parsing%20failed%3A%20Expected%20non-empty%20key%20at%3A&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i64.637j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), the two earliest links (the first being yours), despite not having played Minecraft before. I would consider that question to be lacking evidence of research which could explain the downvotes. You could say, for example, that you had attempted this method or searched these websites in an attempt to solve your problem. This could also be used to improve your other question to a lesser extent, where your only evidence of research is restarting the app and deleting/reinstalling.

The second is to give as much information as possible that could potentially be helpful in providing the answer. This is quite relevant for your second question about Fortnite on the mobile, where both the phone make, the software e.g. IOS 12.1.4, and the Fortnite app version (both previous and what you are attempting to update to), could easily be relevant to your question and is easily accessible information. A screenshot of the error message is helpful too so viewers can read the exact error message you received. Did you attempt this on other devices such as a Nintendo Switch and have the same issue? Is this the only time you've had the issue, or does this happen repeatedly? That last one is particularly relevant for your question, since you said you solved it by reinstalling the app - do you need an alternate solution if that was the only time you had the issue?

[Looking at your other questions](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/189302/awesome-gamer-333?tab=questions), those tips can be applied for most if not all of them.

Generally with question bans, it is recommended to edit and improve your previous questions to make them more likely to be upvoted, which can help lift a question ban. Even answered questions get views later (and your Fortnite one is still unanswered). You could update your questions based on those tips, even those without a negative score. And, as Blueberry Gumdrops said, don't delete questions - you're better off editing and improving those questions.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few good things you can do in the case of a question ban:

- **Edit your questions** to make them better. This will bump them to the homepage and allow it to get upvoted if you've made it good.
- **Provide some good answers.** This actually helps significantly to lift question-bans.
- **Don't delete your questions.** Deleted questions count against you just as much as non-deleted ones.

It may take some time for the ban to be lifted, but it will happen if you do these three things.

For more information, see [What can I do when getting "We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th).